Find number of $7$ digit numbers using all non-zero digits such that $a_{1}<a_{2}<a_{3}<a_{4}>a_{5}>a_{6}>a_{7}$

Find number of $7$ digit numbers of the form $a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}a_{4}a_{5}a_{6}a_{7}$ using all non-zero digits such that $a_{1}<a_{2}<a_{3}<a_{4}>a_{5}>a_{6}>a_{7}$ and repetiton of digits is allowed.

My Solution:
Case $1$ No digit is repeating
In this case we have to select total $7$ digits out of $9$ non-zero digits which can be done in ${9\choose7}$ ways and out of these $7$ selected digits maximum digit will be in middle and for left $3$ digits will be selected in ${6\choose 3}$ ways and ways to arrange them is only $1$ hence answer to this case is ${9\choose 3}\cdot {6\choose3}$
Case $2$ One digit is repeating
In this case we have select total $6$ digits out of $9$ non-zero digits which can be done in ${9\choose 6}$ ways and out of these $6$ selected digits, digit with maximum value will be in middle and it will not repeat and from remaining $5$ digit one will repeat. And of the repeating digit one will be on left side and other will be on right side so we have select only two more numbers from other left digits. Hence answer to this case is ${9\choose 6}{5\choose 1}{4\choose 2}$
Case $3$ Two repeating digits
Answer to this case is ${9\choose 5}{4\choose 2}{2\choose 1}$
Case $4$ Three repeating digits
Answer to this case is ${9\choose 4}$
Hence total answer is ${9\choose 7}{6\choose 3}+{9\choose 6}{5\choose 1}{4\choose 2}+{9\choose 5}{4\choose 2}{2\choose 1}+{9\choose 4}=4878$
My doubt: Is there any other method to solve this problem for example like Recursion method or generating function method?

FWIW, I got $4878$ with a brute-force solution, which agrees with your answer.

Consider the possible values for the maximum, $a_4$.  We need $a_4\geq 4$ to get three strictly decreasing digits below it.  Once $a_4=k$ is chosen, there are $k-1$ values beneath it to choose from, so there are $\binom {k-1}3$ ways to choose the triple to the left, and the triple to the right.  Of course, we don't care if the two triples intersect nor even if they coincide.  Thus there are $\binom {k-1}3^2$ ways of choosing the two triples.
Thus the answer is $$\sum_{k=4}^9\binom {k-1}3^2=4878$$  confirming your result.
One advantage of this method is that it is easy to extend it to higher values than $9$ (just change the upper limit of the sum) and to more than $3$ values on the sides (just change the $3$ in one or both of the binomial symbols in the summand).
